# Akka stream of objects over http

Tags: java, stream, akka, akka-stream

I have got a piece of code (see bellow) which spawns a server that echoes every stream of ByteString it receives from port 6001. The example also defines a client that connects to the server and sends a stream of ByteString containing a list of characters from letter 'a' to 'z'.

My question at this point is, **does akka offer a way to send and receive a Stream of objects instead of ByStreams over http?**  For instance, objects of class Client.

If so, how could I send and receive such a stream of objects? Could you provide me a snippet that shows how to carry it out?

Akka documentation is not user-friendly for non-toy examples...

Thanks for your help

public class TcpEcho {

```
/**
 * Use without parameters to start both client and server.
 *
 * Use parameters `server 0.0.0.0 6001` to start server listening on port
 * 6001.
 *
 * Use parameters `client 127.0.0.1 6001` to start client connecting to
 * server on 127.0.0.1:6001.
 *
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("ClientAndServer");
        InetSocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 6000);
        server(system, serverAddress);
        client(system, serverAddress);
    } else {
        InetSocketAddress serverAddress;
        if (args.length == 3) {
            serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress(args[1], Integer.valueOf(args[2]));
        } else {
            serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 6000);
        }
        if (args[0].equals("server")) {
            ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("Server");
            server(system, serverAddress);
        } else if (args[0].equals("client")) {
            ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("Client");
            client(system, serverAddress);
        }
    }
}

public static void server(ActorSystem system, InetSocketAddress serverAddress) {
    final ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

    final Sink<IncomingConnection, CompletionStage<Done>> handler = Sink.foreach(conn -> {
        System.out.println("Client connected from: " + conn.remoteAddress());
        conn.handleWith(Flow.<ByteString> create(), materializer);
    });

    final CompletionStage<ServerBinding> bindingFuture = Tcp.get(system)
            .bind(serverAddress.getHostString(), serverAddress.getPort()).to(handler).run(materializer);

    bindingFuture.whenComplete((binding, throwable) -> {
        System.out.println("Server started, listening on: " + binding.localAddress());
    });

    bindingFuture.exceptionally(e -> {
        System.err.println("Server could not bind to " + serverAddress + " : " + e.getMessage());
        system.terminate();
        return null;
    });

}

public static void client(ActorSystem system, InetSocketAddress serverAddress) {
    final ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

    final List<ByteString> testInput = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        testInput.add(ByteString.fromString(String.valueOf(c)));
    }

    Source<ByteString, NotUsed> responseStream = Source.from(testInput)
            .via(Tcp.get(system).outgoingConnection(serverAddress.getHostString(), serverAddress.getPort()));

    CompletionStage<ByteString> result = responseStream.runFold(ByteString.empty(), (acc, in) -> acc.concat(in),
            materializer);

    result.whenComplete((success, failure) -> {

        if (failure != null) {
            System.err.println("Failure: " + failure.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Result: " + success.utf8String());
        }
        System.out.println("Shutting down client");
        system.terminate();

    });
}
```

}

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.3/java/stream/stream-graphs.html#Bidirectional_Flows) of how to create Bidi flow, I think it does more or less, what you're asking for?

Comment: I didn't take a look, but I will. In any case, do you have a better idea / suggestion in the shape of a snippet of code? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`akka.stream.{javadsl,scaladsl}.Framing` contains utilities to help you build consistent messages. For example, you can send your messages through `Framing.simpleFramingProtocolEncoder(maxLength)` to automatically add length information to them. On the other end, `Framing.simpleFramingProtocolDecoder(maxLength)` will take care of decoding the message according to its enclosed length information.

If you want to manipulate plain objects, you just have to serialize them into a `ByteString` before sending them through the encoder, and deserialize them from the `ByteString` after receiving their representation from the decoder.